# Pivot4j/Olap4j adding condition to where clause of generated query

Tags: olap, olap4j

I have a ROLAP cube - Pivot4j 0.9, Olap4j 1.1.0, MySQL.

When I run the following MDX I can see an additional condition in the where clause which causes the resulting statement to return no rows.

```
SELECT Hierarchize({[Measures].[Unique Users]}) ON COLUMNS,  NON EMPTY Hierarchize([dimBrowserType].AllMembers) ON ROWS  FROM [Sessions]
```

Resulting SQL...

```
17:28:08,536 DEBUG RolapUtil:319 - Segment.load: done executing sql [
select `meta_date`.`date_day` as `c0`, count(distinct `sessions_551d03b3e4b0dc830608a95b`.`userId`) as `m0` 
from `meta_date` as `meta_date`, `sessions_551d03b3e4b0dc830608a95b` as `sessions_551d03b3e4b0dc830608a95b` 
where `sessions_551d03b3e4b0dc830608a95b`.`daykey` = `meta_date`.`daykey` 
and `meta_date`.`date_day` = '2015-01-01' 
group by `meta_date`.`date_day`
], exec+fetch 44 ms, 0 rows, ex=7, close=7, open=[]
```

Olap4j has added this clause...

```
and `meta_date`.`date_day` = '2015-01-01'
```

...which does not relate to anything in the intial MDX. There is no data for this particular value of date_day so the query returns no data.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have an 'all member' on the date hierarchy. The MDX specifications say that in this case, the first member is used.

Try adding `hasAll=true` to your hierarchy.

Comment: I have several time dimensions in the cube. One of them was set to hasAll="false"